# Altering The Sorting Arrows In an R Shiny tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I didn't see anything here or in http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny that seems to hit on this problem.

In an R Shiny tabPanel output, the sorting arrows align with the right side of the search fields at the bottom of the page.

Here's a pretty good example:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html

Is there a way to make them align just to the right of the column name text up top?

Alternatively (or possibly both), is there a way to change the color of the arrows?
The default greyish doesn't really stand out. Bonus points to make the up and down arrows different colors.

Doing it directly in RShiny is best, but I could muddle my way through .js or .css if needed.

I'm trying to head off imminent support requests of "the column is sorting wrong" and "I can't see the arrows" before I push into production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of that shiny example you showed they show that you can pass in through the `options` parameter options to the rendering for the `DataTable` table, via the `shiny::renderDataTable()` function.

Hopefully the http://datatables.net/ site has documentation on what you want if it's indeed possible

If you look at Developer Tools on the http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html page maybe you can see what element would need to be changed.

Comment: Thank you a ton for pointing me to that datatables.net site. I would have never seen it otherwise. The Shiny docs don't really make reference of it that I could find.  I just added a helptext of "click on the column name to sort" and it works fine for the users.  Now to get a pull request in on the Shiny docs.